# How do I call a base class's own method from another method when it's overridden?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding, dynamic-binding

```
public class Parent{

    private Object oBase;

    public Object getObject(){

        // [some logic] 
        return oBase;
    }

    public String getObjectValue(){

        return getObject().getValue();
    }



public class Child extends Parent {

    private Object oChild;

    public Object getObject(){

        return oChild;
    }


    public Object getObjectValue(){

        return getObject().getValue();
    }

    public String getParentObjectValue(){

        return super.getObjectValue();
    }
}
```

In the above template, I need a way to make sure that the getObject() in Parent.getObjectValue() calls Parent.getObject() and not Child.getObject(), so that the child class can have getters to oBase and oChild.

I've tried using ((Parent)this).getObject().getValue() in Parent.getObjectValue(), but it still polymorphs to the child definition. Is there way to force static binding in java for a specific call?

I'm trying to avoid duplicating the [some logic] from Parent.getObject() in Parent.getObjectValue(), but I guess I'll have to if there's really no way around it.

Comment: I guess that you should make it private then.

Comment: If you create the object like  Parent parent = new Parent(); then parent methods will be called and if you create object like Parent parent = new Child(); then child methods will be called...

Comment: `super` is made to call the base class variables and method. You can use the super.yourMethod() in child class method. Read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html it will also help you to understand the method overriding concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either make the `getObject()` method private, or change the method name so that polymorphism will not kick on. Overall, you'll have to rethink your design.

Other options are to extract the [some logic] to a third method and invoke this from both `getObject()` and `getObjectValue()`. Please keep in mind the Command Query separation principle when you use this design.

Comment: The [some logic] part is actually what's doing the retrieval of what getObject() returns (based on an argument, just wanted to keep my question as on topic as possible ;) ), so CQS is satisfied. I've gone with the private method approach, which is called by getObject() and getObjectValue() in the parent class. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't force a call to the `Parent`'s method from outside the child class, due to polymorphism. Indeed, for a `Child` object, the parent method does not exist anymore, because it has been overriden.

You don't seem to need any aspect of polymorphism here (though it's hard to tell without more information). If, indeed, you do not need it (different use cases), then change your methods' names so that it does not happen.

*Note: If you're in the child class, then you can use `super`, but I don't think this is your case.*

Answer (score 0):

You could just refer to the private field 'oBase' directly, instead of using the 'getObject()' method.

Comment: But the OP says that there is some logic in the getObject() method that (s)he wishes to execute

Comment: I see ;) Then your answer is correct. He needs to rethink his design a bit.